# 1С При изменении одного реквизита менять автоматически другой

Tags: 1с

В документе есть реквизиты "КонтактноеЛицо" и "Телефон". Нужно чтобы при изменении контактного лица автоматически вставлялся телефон. Данные пользователь выбирает из справочника "КонтактныеЛицаКонтрагентов".
Пишу код, но при выборе контактного лица в поле с телефоном ничего не происходит.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура КонтактноеЛицоПриИзменении(Элемент)
   КонтактноеЛицо = Объект.КонтактноеЛицо;
   Объект.Телефон = ПолучитьТел (КонтактноеЛицо);
КонецПроцедуры

 &НаСервереБезКонтекста
Функция   ПолучитьТел (КонтактноеЛицо)
     Возврат КонтактноеЛицо.ОсновнойТел;
КонецФункции
```

Comment: К сожалению нет под рукой платформы, чтобы продемонстрировать, как это должно работать. Вы явно что-то делаете не то. Вы меня извините, но мне кажется, что stackowerflow, не самое лучшее место для получения информации по программированию в 1С. Не пробовали заглядывать сюда: http://mista.ru/tutor_1c/index.htm или сюда: http://www.forum.mista.ru/index.php. Там охотней ответят и людей в теме в разы больше. Вдобавок есть замечательное пособие Радченко "1C: Предприятие:Практическое пособие разработчика. Примеры и типовые приемы". Там такие вещи достаточно подробно разобраны.

Comment: @Sublihim хорошо,спасибо, посмотрю.
Да, я заметила что я делаю что-то не то, т.к. оно не работает :))))

Comment: да не то даже в каком-то, слегка, концептуальном смысле )

Comment: @Sublihim Разобралась, спасибо, на этом сайте подсказали, где вы ссылку дали. Оказывается код правильный, ошибка была в типе поля "телефон". Это должно быть число, а у меня элемент справочника

Comment: ну, вот и хорошо :)